# Running .ps1 file how do I bypass the 'Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your device?' UAC Windows Powershell Message?

Tags: powershell

I run a .bat file to trigger the .ps1 file and it works fine. If the spooler is not running it will start it up. But in executing the file it brings up the UAC dialog box asking if 'I want to allow changes'. The file must run without interaction as it will be called from a scheduler every few minutes. FYI starting the Spooler service is just a test as it will monitor a different service. It was my understanding that the -NoProfile would bypass the UAC dialog box.

Bat File...
@ECHO OFF
PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dpn0.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"

ps1 File...

```
$Service = Get-Service -Name spooler
    if ($Service.Status -ne "Running")
    {         
        (Get-Date).ToString() + " - Service stopped." >> C:\Scripts\log.txt
        Start-Service spooler
    }
```

Comment: _"The file must run without interaction as it will be called from a scheduler every few minutes."_ => Set up the task to __Run with the highest privileges__ ?

Comment: You don't need to call your script from cmd if this will be a scheduled task by the way. You can simply `powershell.exe -File`